# How to read this CDATA using NSXMLParser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsxmlparser, cdata

I am familiar with NSXMLParser and I use it to read some XML lines, but I had an issue about these lines:

```
    <item>
    <title>Price Drop: AngerOfStick2  (Games)</title>
    <link>http://appshopper.com/games/angerofstick2</link>
    <category>Games</category>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">http://appshopper.com/games/angerofstick2-Wed, 18 Apr 2012 10:49:58 EDT-price</guid>
    <description><![CDATA[
        <img src="http://images.appshopper.com/icons/408/347359.png" align="left"/>
        <h3>AngerOfStick2 1.1.6</h3><br/>
        <b>Device:</b> iOS iPhone<br />
        <b>Category:</b> Games<br />
        <b>Price:</b> $.99 -> Free, <b>Version:</b> 1.1.6 (<a href="/link/angerofstick2">iTunes</a>) <br/><br/>
        <img src="http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/106/Purple/v4/f7/91/f9/f791f91e-454f-9525-2ebc-9c341707d0ad/mza_5266557554023051353.640x960-75.jpg" width="480" align="right"/>
        <b>Description:</b><br /><br />
        Limited Time SALE! 50% OFF! Get it now and don’t miss out!============UPDATES INFO============= version 1.0.1 :-Game Center Support-RETINA Icon Supportversion 1.0.2 :- Doodle Runner ( Add New Mode )version 1.0.3 :- Survival Mode ( Add New Mode ) version 1.0.4 :- Jump Jump Mode ( Add New Mode ) version 1.0.6 :-Mulitiplayer Mode: 1 vs 1   ( Add New Mode )------Main Update Plan------=====================================User say :- &quot; This is a wonderful game! It has a perfect balance of fast action-packed entertainment, and it is completely addicting! I would recommend this game to anyone! &quot;- &quot; Get this game! It's one of the best games I've played for a while! GET THIS GAME! &quot;- &quot; This game is the beast so addicte to it I can't stop playing it. &quot;- &quot; This is a great game! Really REALLY entertaining when you get into the zone. 5 stars !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  &quot;- &quot; Ohh yeaaaaaaaa oh yeaaaa oh yea! &quot;Introduction:- Anger of stick 2nd Story -Unknown enemies in the city emerge and the hero continues to remove enemies with a variety of weapons, and helicopters and robots that can devastate all enemies at a time.Special Features: - Action : You can feel the realistic fighting action with 130 behaviors and Hero air combo action is added that can remove all enemies at one time.- Weapons: Enemies can be handled lightly by using helicopters and robots in the map, and weapons such as M1911, UZI, Granade Luncher, Spas_12, SG550, Remington_870, Flamethrower, Ray-gun, Mini-gun, Bat, and Sword.- Map: Cities, deserts and forests are configured in the map and the fighting action inside building is added.Tips:- When enemies come on the both sides, all enemies will be fallen down on seizing and throwing enemies back.- An infinite combo attack is available with Hero air combo.- Enemies can be handled by well-using robots and helicopters on the streets.- To avoid the attacks from guns and robots of enemies, button on the key to move to the left is necessary.Support Information: For additional support, please contact: E-mail : pjh097@gmail.com<br/><br/><b>What's New</b><br /><br />Fixed some bug.<br/><br/>
        <a href="http://appshopper.com/games/angerofstick2">AngerOfStick2</a><br /><br />
    ]]></description>
    <pubDate>Wed, 18 Apr 2012 10:49:58 EDT</pubDate>
    </item>
```

How can I get img src from description element?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this method...

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock
{
    NSString *someString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:CDATABlock encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
// reparse the string to extract the img src attribute value... 
}
```

hoping this helps... :D

Comment: But be warned: you can't do the obvious thing and use `NSXMLParser` right then and there to parse the string obtained from the CDATA.  From the [Lion release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/Cocoa/Foundation.html): "NSXMLParser is now threadsafe. However, it is not reentrant on a given thread; don't call -parse on an NSXMLParser from within a delegate callback of another NSXMLParser."

Comment: it works good but i am getting partial data could u suggest whats wrong with me

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava can you tell how exactly you can re-parse it?

Comment: @Jessica you can create a new instance of NSXMLParser inside this call back and parse "someString" as required.